# Undocumented pppd exit code

Tags: linux, osx, vpn, pptp

If my machine (OSX 10.9.2) is not connected to the Internet and I want to establish pptp connection by using **pppd**:

```
$ sudo /usr/sbin/pppd serviceid 5BE14D3A-7B94-4704-ADE0-9883B189199E debug logfile /tmp/ppp.log plugin /System/Library/SystemConfiguration/PPPController.bundle/Contents/PlugIns/PPPDialogs.ppp plugin pptp.ppp remoteaddress 11.22.33.44 redialcount 1 redialtimer 5 idle 1800 mru 1500 mtu 1448 receive-all novj 0:0 noipdefault ipcp-accept-local ipcp-accept-remote user bbbbbb password cccccc hide-password noaskpassword looplocal defaultroute usepeerdns mppe-128 nodetach logfd 1
```

pppd outputs:

```
Thu Mar 27 15:09:30 2014 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!
Thu Mar 27 15:09:30 2014 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!
```

and terminates with exit code **25**:

```
$ echo $?
25
```

**Why pppd returns with exit code which is not [documented](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/pppd.8.html)?** Expected exit codes are in the range [0, 19]. Where does this exit code come from? Does this exit code have description? Are there any other "hidden" exit codes for pppd?

If I connect to the Internet and run the same command, pptp connection gets established.

Last couple of lines of *dtruss* output are:

```
$ /usr/bin/sudo dtruss /usr/sbin/pppd serviceid 5BE14D3A-7B94-4704-ADE0-9883B189199E debug logfile /tmp/ppp.log plugin /System/Library/SystemConfiguration/PPPController.bundle/Contents/PlugIns/PPPDialogs.ppp plugin pptp.ppp remoteaddress 11.22.33.44 redialcount 1 redialtimer 5 idle 1800 mru 1500 mtu 1448 receive-all novj 0:0 noipdefault ipcp-accept-local ipcp-accept-remote user bbbbbbb password cccccccc hide-password noaskpassword looplocal defaultroute usepeerdns mppe-128 nodetach logfd 1
Fri Mar 28 10:31:10 2014 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!
Fri Mar 28 10:31:10 2014 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!
Fri Mar 28 10:31:10 2014 : PPTP connecting to server '11.22.33.44' (77.75.123.187)...
Fri Mar 28 10:31:10 2014 : PPTP connect errno = 49 Can't assign requested address
SYSCALL(args)        = return
close(0x3)       = 0 0
getuid(0x0, 0x1103, 0x7FFF772B14E0)      = 0 0
getgid(0x0, 0x1103, 0x0)         = 0 0
getuid(0x7FDEA8D00A80, 0x0, 0x1)         = 0 0
seteuid(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)       = 0 0
open_nocancel("/var/root/.ppprc\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)      = -1 Err#2
seteuid(0x0, 0x7FFF76AB4430, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)         = 0 0
open("/tmp/ppp.log\0", 0xA09, 0x1A4)         = -1 Err#17
open("/tmp/ppp.log\0", 0x9, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)      = 3 0
open_nocancel("/System/Library/SystemConfiguration/PPPController.bundle/Contents/PlugIns/PPPDialogs.ppp\0", 0x1100004, 0x7FDEA8D00D70)       = 4 0
__sysctl(0x7FFF54902F38, 0x2, 0x7FFF76AB4180)        = 0 0
fstatfs64(0x4, 0x7FFF54902F88, 0x0)      = 0 0
getdirentries64(0x4, 0x7FDEAA000600, 0x1000)         = 88 0
getdirentries64(0x4, 0x7FDEAA000600, 0x1000)         = 0 0
close_nocancel(0x4)      = 0 0
open_nocancel("/System/Library/SystemConfiguration/PPPController.bundle/Contents/PlugIns/PPPDialogs.ppp/Contents\0", 0x1100004, 0x7FDEA8D01173)      = 4 0
fstatfs64(0x4, 0x7FFF54902F58, 0x0)      = 0 0
getdirentries64(0x4, 0x7FDEAA000600, 0x1000)         = 240 0
getdirentries64(0x4, 0x7FDEAA000600, 0x1000)         = 0 0
close_nocancel(0x4)      = 0 0
open("/System/Library/SystemConfiguration/PPPController.bundle/Contents/PlugIns/PPPDialogs.ppp/Contents/Info.plist\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)       = 4 0
fstat64(0x4, 0x7FFF54903218, 0x0)        = 0 0
read(0x4, "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC \"-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN\" \"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd\">\n<plist version=\"1.0\">\n<dict>\n\t<key>BuildMachineOSBuild</key>\n\t<string>13C40z</string>\n\t<key>CFBundleDevelopmentReg", 0x4F1)      = 1265 0
close(0x4)       = 0 0
stat64("/System/Library/SystemConfiguration/PPPController.bundle/Contents/PlugIns/PPPDialogs.ppp/Contents/MacOS/PPPDialogs\0", 0x7FFF54903C08, 0x7FFF54904156)   = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/libesp.dylib\0", 0x7FFF549031C8, 0x7FFF54904070)        = -1 Err#2
stat64("/System/Library/SystemConfiguration/PPPController.bundle/Contents/PlugIns/PPPDialogs.ppp/Contents/MacOS/PPPDialogs\0", 0x7FFF54902E88, 0x7FFF54903D30)   = 0 0
stat64("/System/Library/SystemConfiguration/PPPController.bundle/Contents/PlugIns/PPPDialogs.ppp/Contents/MacOS/PPPDialogs\0", 0x7FFF54903B18, 0xF9A90)      = 0 0
open("/System/Library/SystemConfiguration/PPPController.bundle/Contents/PlugIns/PPPDialogs.ppp/Contents/MacOS/PPPDialogs\0", 0x0, 0x1FF)         = 4 0
read(0x4, "\317\372\355\376\a\0", 0x200)         = 512 0
close(0x4)       = 0 0
stat64("/System/Library/SystemConfiguration/PPPController.bundle/Contents/PlugIns/PPPDialogs.ppp/Contents/MacOS/PPPDialogs\0", 0x7FFF54902E68, 0x7FFF54903D10)   = 0 0
open("/System/Library/SystemConfiguration/PPPController.bundle/Contents/PlugIns/PPPDialogs.ppp/Contents/MacOS/PPPDialogs\0", 0x0, 0x0)       = 4 0
pread(0x4, "\317\372\355\376\a\0", 0x1000, 0x0)      = 4096 0
fcntl(0x4, 0x3D, 0x7FFF54901190)         = 0 0
mmap(0x10B38C000, 0x2000, 0x5, 0x12, 0x4, 0x0)       = 0x10B38C000 0
mmap(0x10B38E000, 0x1000, 0x3, 0x12, 0x4, 0x2000)        = 0x10B38E000 0
mmap(0x10B38F000, 0x26F0, 0x1, 0x12, 0x4, 0x3000)        = 0x10B38F000 0
close(0x4)       = 0 0
open_nocancel("/System/Library/Extensions/pptp.ppp\0", 0x1100004, 0x7FDEA8D02370)        = 4 0
fstatfs64(0x4, 0x7FFF54902F88, 0x0)      = 0 0
getdirentries64(0x4, 0x7FDEAA000600, 0x1000)         = 88 0
getdirentries64(0x4, 0x7FDEAA000600, 0x1000)         = 0 0
close_nocancel(0x4)      = 0 0
open_nocancel("/System/Library/Extensions/pptp.ppp/Contents\0", 0x1100004, 0x7FDEA8D02573)       = 4 0
fstatfs64(0x4, 0x7FFF54902F58, 0x0)      = 0 0
getdirentries64(0x4, 0x7FDEAA000600, 0x1000)         = 232 0
getdirentries64(0x4, 0x7FDEAA000600, 0x1000)         = 0 0
close_nocancel(0x4)      = 0 0
open("/System/Library/Extensions/pptp.ppp/Contents/Info.plist\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)    = 4 0
fstat64(0x4, 0x7FFF54903218, 0x0)        = 0 0
geteuid(0x100000001103, 0x110000001100, 0x10B356308)         = 0 0
setsid(0x50000000603, 0x60000000600, 0x7FFF772B15A8)         = 3077 0
socket(0x22, 0x3, 0x1)       = 3 0
connect(0x3, 0x7FFF549046B0, 0x8)        = 0 0
fcntl(0x3, 0x3, 0x0)         = 2 0
fcntl(0x3, 0x4, 0x6)         = 0 0
socket(0x2, 0x2, 0x0)        = 4 0
open_nocancel("/usr/sbin\0", 0x1100004, 0x7FFF922AEB6E)      = 5 0
fstatfs64(0x5, 0x7FFF549031B8, 0x0)      = 0 0
getdirentries64(0x5, 0x7FDEAA000600, 0x1000)         = 4080 0
getdirentries64(0x5, 0x7FDEAA000600, 0x1000)         = 4072 0
getdirentries64(0x5, 0x7FDEAA000600, 0x1000)         = 648 0
getdirentries64(0x5, 0x7FDEAA000600, 0x1000)         = 0 0
close_nocancel(0x5)      = 0 0
stat64("/usr/sbin/Contents\0", 0x7FFF549039D8, 0x7FFF54903ABF)       = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/sbin/Resources\0", 0x7FFF549039D8, 0x7FFF54903ABF)      = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/sbin/Support Files\0", 0x7FFF549039D8, 0x7FFF54903ABF)      = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/sbin\0", 0x7FFF54903F58, 0x7FFF5490406B)        = 0 0
open_nocancel("/usr/sbin\0", 0x1100004, 0x7FFF922AEB6E)      = 5 0
fstatfs64(0x5, 0x7FFF54903188, 0x0)      = 0 0
getdirentries64(0x5, 0x7FDEAA000600, 0x1000)         = 4080 0
getdirentries64(0x5, 0x7FDEAA000600, 0x1000)         = 4072 0
getdirentries64(0x5, 0x7FDEAA000600, 0x1000)         = 648 0
getdirentries64(0x5, 0x7FDEAA000600, 0x1000)         = 0 0
close_nocancel(0x5)      = 0 0
stat64("/usr/sbin/pppd\0", 0x7FFF54903DC8, 0x7FFF54903E7E)       = 0 0
open("/usr/sbin/pppd\0", 0x0, 0x1FF)         = 5 0
read(0x5, "\317\372\355\376\a\0", 0x200)         = 512 0
close(0x5)       = 0 0
geteuid(0x7FDEA8D00030, 0x7FFF76F80258, 0x49656E69)      = 0 0
kevent64(0x5, 0x7FFF549043A8, 0x1)       = 1 0
open("/dev/null\0", 0x2, 0x0)        = 6 0
__sysctl(0x7FFF54903AC0, 0x2, 0x7FFF54903AD0)        = 0 0
getuid(0x7FDEAA001743, 0x7FFF54903D60, 0x0)      = 0 0
getgid(0x7FDEAA001748, 0x7FFF54903D60, 0x0)      = 0 0
sigaction(0x1, 0x7FFF54904758, 0x0)      = 0 0
sigaction(0x2, 0x7FFF54904758, 0x0)      = 0 0
sigaction(0xF, 0x7FFF54904758, 0x0)      = 0 0
sigaction(0x14, 0x7FFF54904758, 0x0)         = 0 0
sigaction(0x12, 0x7FFF54904758, 0x0)         = 0 0
sigaction(0x13, 0x7FFF54904758, 0x0)         = 0 0
sigaction(0x1E, 0x7FFF54904758, 0x0)         = 0 0
sigaction(0x1F, 0x7FFF54904758, 0x0)         = 0 0
sigaction(0x6, 0x7FFF54904758, 0x0)      = 0 0
sigaction(0xE, 0x7FFF54904758, 0x0)      = 0 0
sigaction(0x8, 0x7FFF54904758, 0x0)      = 0 0
sigaction(0x4, 0x7FFF54904758, 0x0)      = 0 0
sigaction(0xD, 0x7FFF54904758, 0x0)      = 0 0
sigaction(0x3, 0x7FFF54904758, 0x0)      = 0 0
sigaction(0xB, 0x7FFF54904758, 0x0)      = 0 0
sigaction(0xA, 0x7FFF54904758, 0x0)      = 0 0
sigaction(0x7, 0x7FFF54904758, 0x0)      = 0 0
sigaction(0x1B, 0x7FFF54904758, 0x0)         = 0 0
sigaction(0xC, 0x7FFF54904758, 0x0)      = 0 0
sigaction(0x5, 0x7FFF54904758, 0x0)      = 0 0
sigaction(0x1A, 0x7FFF54904758, 0x0)         = 0 0
sigaction(0x18, 0x7FFF54904758, 0x0)         = 0 0
sigaction(0x19, 0x7FFF54904758, 0x0)         = 0 0
stat64("/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security\0", 0x7FFF549040D0, 0x7FFF8E1A1463)       = 0 0
stat64("/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security\0", 0x7FFF54903188, 0x7FFF54904030)       = 0 0
csops(0xC05, 0x7, 0x7FFF54904510)        = 0 0
workq_kernreturn(0x20, 0x0, 0x1)         = 0 0
kevent64(0x5, 0x0, 0x0)      = 1 0
kevent64(0x5, 0x10B3AC3C8, 0x1)      = 1 0
workq_kernreturn(0x20, 0x0, 0x1)         = 0 0
kevent64(0x5, 0x0, 0x0)      = 1 0
workq_kernreturn(0x20, 0x0, 0x1)         = 0 0
workq_kernreturn(0x20, 0x0, 0x1)         = 0 0
kevent64(0x5, 0x7FFF75519130, 0x1)       = 1 0
workq_kernreturn(0x20, 0x0, 0x1)         = 0 0
workq_kernreturn(0x20, 0x0, 0x1)         = 0 0
kevent64(0x5, 0x10BC80D88, 0x1)      = 1 0
workq_kernreturn(0x20, 0x0, 0x1)         = 0 0
__sysctl(0x7FFF54903A90, 0x2, 0x7FFF54903AA0)        = 0 0
getuid(0x7FDEAA00170E, 0x7FFF54903D30, 0x0)      = 0 0
getgid(0x7FDEAA001713, 0x7FFF54903D30, 0x0)      = 0 0
csops(0x0, 0x0, 0x7FFF54903F04)      = 0 0
issetugid(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)         = 0 0
pread(0x3, "\312\376\272\276\0", 0x1000, 0x0)        = 4096 0
pread(0x3, "\317\372\355\376\a\0", 0x1000, 0x1000)       = 4096 0
fcntl(0x3, 0x3D, 0x7FFF54901350)         = 0 0
mmap(0x10B357000, 0x2000, 0x5, 0x12, 0x3, 0x1000)        = 0x10B357000 0
mmap(0x10B359000, 0x1000, 0x3, 0x12, 0x3, 0x3000)        = 0x10B359000 0
mmap(0x10B35A000, 0x2050, 0x1, 0x12, 0x3, 0x4000)        = 0x10B35A000 0
close(0x3)       = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib\0", 0x7FFF54902D98, 0x7FFF54903C30)      = 0 0
stat64("/System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration\0", 0x7FFF54902D98, 0x7FFF54903C30)      = 0 0
stat64("/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation\0", 0x7FFF54902D98, 0x7FFF54903C30)        = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib\0", 0x7FFF54902D98, 0x7FFF54903C30)       = 0 0
stat64("/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit\0", 0x7FFF54902D98, 0x7FFF54903C30)      = 0 0
stat64("/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security\0", 0x7FFF54902D98, 0x7FFF54903C30)        = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib\0", 0x7FFF54902908, 0x7FFF549037A0)   = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib\0", 0x7FFF54902908, 0x7FFF549037A0)        = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib\0", 0x7FFF54902908, 0x7FFF549037A0 = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib\0", 0x7FFF54902908, 0x7FFF549037A0)    = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib\0", 0x7FFF54902908, 0x7FFF549037A0) = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib\0", 0x7FFF54902908, 0x7FFF549037A0)    = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib\0", 0x7FFF54902908, 0x7FFF549037A0)    = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib\0", 0x7FFF54902908, 0x7FFF549037A0)  = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib\0", 0x7FFF54902908, 0x7FFF549037A0)  = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib\0", 0x7FFF54902908, 0x7FFF549037A0)   = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib\0", 0x7FFF54902908, 0x7FFF549037A0) = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib\0", 0x7FFF54902908, 0x7FFF549037A0) = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib\0", 0x7FFF54902908, 0x7FFF549037A0) = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib\0", 0x7FFF54902908, 0x7FFF549037A0)       = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib\0", 0x7FFF54902908, 0x7FFF549037A0)    = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib\0", 0x7FFF54902908, 0x7FFF549037A0)        = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib\0", 0x7FFF54902908, 0x7FFF549037A0)        = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib\0", 0x7FFF54902908, 0x7FFF549037A0 = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib\0", 0x7FFF54902908, 0x7FFF549037A0)       = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib\0", 0x7FFF54902908, 0x7FFF549037A0)    = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib\0", 0x7FFF54902908, 0x7FFF549037A0)       = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib\0", 0x7FFF54902908, 0x7FFF549037A0)      = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib\0", 0x7FFF54902908, 0x7FFF549037A0)       = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib\0", 0x7FFF54902908, 0x7FFF549037A0)         = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib\0", 0x7FFF54902908, 0x7FFF549037A0)      = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib\0", 0x7FFF54902908, 0x7FFF549037A0)      = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libsystem_stats.dylib\0", 0x7FFF54902908, 0x7FFF549037A0)        = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libunc.dylib\0", 0x7FFF54902908, 0x7FFF549037A0)     = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib\0", 0x7FFF54902908, 0x7FFF549037A0)  = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib\0", 0x7FFF54902908, 0x7FFF549037A0)     = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib\0", 0x7FFF54901B48, 0x7FFF549029E0)         = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/libauto.dylib\0", 0x7FFF54901B48, 0x7FFF549029E0)       = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib\0", 0x7FFF549015F8, 0x7FFF54902490)         = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib\0", 0x7FFF549015F8, 0x7FFF54902490)      = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib\0", 0x7FFF549014D8, 0x7FFF54902370)       = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib\0", 0x7FFF54902B18, 0x7FFF549039B0)      = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/libz.1.dylib\0", 0x7FFF54902B18, 0x7FFF549039B0)        = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib\0", 0x7FFF54902C48, 0x7FFF54903AE0)    = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/libxar.1.dylib\0", 0x7FFF54902BA8, 0x7FFF54903A40)      = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib\0", 0x7FFF54902BA8, 0x7FFF54903A40)        = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/libpam.2.dylib\0", 0x7FFF54902BA8, 0x7FFF54903A40)      = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/libOpenScriptingUtil.dylib\0", 0x7FFF54902BA8, 0x7FFF54903A40) = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib\0", 0x7FFF54902A78, 0x7FFF54903910)        = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib\0", 0x7FFF54902A78, 0x7FFF54903910)         = 0 0
getpid(0x7FFF54903CF8, 0x10B352004, 0xEA60)      = 3077 0
shm_open(0x7FFF92E96CE4, 0x0, 0x0)       = 3 0
mmap(0x0, 0x1000, 0x1, 0x1, 0x3, 0x0)        = 0x10B38B000 0
close_nocancel(0x3)      = 0 0
geteuid(0x20000000303, 0x30000000300, 0x10B356308)       = 0 0
__sysctl(0x7FFF54904640, 0x2, 0x7FFF54904650)        = 0 0
umask(0x1FF, 0x0, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0)        = 18 0
umask(0x12, 0x0, 0x0)        = 511 0
getuid(0x12, 0x0, 0x0)       = 0 0
getgroups(0x10, 0x10B33EE20, 0x0)        = 13 0
__sysctl(0x7FFF54904738, 0x2, 0x7FFF5490472C)        = 0 0
getrlimit(0x1008, 0x7FFF54903DA0, 0x7FFF8BF3CE7C)        = 0 0
open_nocancel("/etc/ppp/options\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)      = -1 Err#2
getuid(0x4, 0x7FFF76AB4430, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)      = 0 0
read(0x4, "\317\372\355\376\a\0", 0x200)         = 512 0
open_nocancel("/etc/ppp/postoptions\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)      = -1 Err#2
geteuid(0x20000000303, 0x30000000300, 0x7FFF772B15A8)        = 0 0
socket(0x22, 0x3, 0x1)       = 4 0
close(0x4)       = 0 0
close(0x3)       = 0 0
getuid(0x7FDEA8E000C0, 0x0, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFF01)      = 0 0
getgid(0x7FDEA8E000C0, 0x0, 0x0)         = 0 0
write(0x1, "Fri Mar 28 10:31:10 2014 : \0", 0x1B)        = 27 0
write(0x1, "publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!\0", 0x27)        = 39 0
write(0x1, "\n\0", 0x1)      = 1 0
__sysctl(0x7FFF54902800, 0x2, 0x7FFF54902810)        = 0 0
getuid(0x7FDEA9802330, 0x7FFF54902AA0, 0x0)      = 0 0
getgid(0x7FDEA9802335, 0x7FFF54902AA0, 0x0)      = 0 0
write(0x1, "Fri Mar 28 10:31:10 2014 : \0", 0x1B)        = 27 0
write(0x1, "publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!\0", 0x27)        = 39 0
write(0x1, "\n\0", 0x1)      = 1 0
guarded_kqueue_np(0x7FFF54903E98, 0x3, 0x7FFF86283A77)       = 5 0
kevent64(0x5, 0x7FFF86296C48, 0x1)       = 0 0
workq_kernreturn(0x10, 0x0, 0x58)        = 0 0
workq_open(0x10, 0x0, 0x0)       = 0 0
bsdthread_create(0x7FFF86283E77, 0x7FFF75518940, 0x10000)        = 188403712 0
kevent64(0x5, 0x7FFF54903F18, 0x1)       = 1 0
kevent64(0x5, 0x10BC80D88, 0x1)      = 1 0
kevent64(0x5, 0x0, 0x0)      = 1 0
workq_kernreturn(0x20, 0x0, 0x1)         = 0 0
thread_selfid(0x0, 0x1DC0, 0x7FFF65505550)       = 88904 0
shared_region_check_np(0x7FFF54901E38, 0x10B2FB000, 0x4)         = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/dtrace/libdtrace_dyld.dylib\0", 0x7FFF54902FE8, 0x7FFF54903F20 = 0 0
open("/usr/lib/dtrace/libdtrace_dyld.dylib\0", 0x0, 0x0)         = 3 0
ioctl(0x3, 0x80086804, 0x7FFF54903D78)       = 0 0
kevent64(0x5, 0x7FFF75519130, 0x1)       = 1 0
workq_kernreturn(0x20, 0x0, 0x1)         = 0 0
thread_selfid(0x10BD04000, 0x7FFF77A55258, 0x1010101)        = 88912 0
workq_kernreturn(0x20, 0x0, 0x1)         = 0 0
open("/dev/dtracehelper\0", 0x2, 0x7FFF54903DF0)         = 3 0
__sysctl(0x7FFF54903648, 0x2, 0x7FFF54903658)        = 0 0
thread_selfid(0x7FFF77A55310, 0x7FFF77A55258, 0x10101)       = 88904 0
bsdthread_register(0x7FFF92F30FBC, 0x7FFF92F30FAC, 0x2000)       = 0 0
mprotect(0x10B353000, 0x88, 0x1)         = 0 0
mprotect(0x10B35D000, 0x1000, 0x0)       = 0 0
mprotect(0x10B373000, 0x1000, 0x0)       = 0 0
mprotect(0x10B374000, 0x1000, 0x0)       = 0 0
mprotect(0x10B38A000, 0x1000, 0x0)       = 0 0
mprotect(0x10B355000, 0x1000, 0x1)       = 0 0
mprotect(0x10B353000, 0x88, 0x3)         = 0 0
mprotect(0x10B353000, 0x88, 0x1)         = 0 0
issetugid(0x7FFF75518480, 0x7FFFFFE00034, 0x7FFFFFE00036)        = 0 0
getpid(0x1, 0x10B356000, 0x49656E69)         = 3077 0
__mac_syscall(0x7FFF853DCE3F, 0x2, 0x7FFF549034C8)       = 0 0
stat64("/AppleInternal\0", 0x7FFF54903548, 0x0)      = -1 Err#2
audit_session_self(0x7FFF54903400, 0x7FFF54903238, 0x4)      = 4099 0
geteuid(0x7FFF54903400, 0x7FFF54903238, 0x0)         = 0 0
getegid(0x7FFF54903400, 0x7FFF54903238, 0x0)         = 0 0
getaudit_addr(0x7FFF549034D8, 0x30, 0x0)         = 0 0
csops(0xC05, 0x7, 0x7FFF549030C0)        = 0 0
getuid(0x7FFF5490371C, 0x7FFF54903718, 0x7FFF54904960)       = 0 0
geteuid(0x103, 0x10000000100, 0x7FFF778F8198)        = 0 0
getuid(0x103, 0x10000000100, 0x0)        = 0 0
__sysctl(0x7FFF54902BC0, 0x4, 0x7FFF54902BD8)        = 0 0
issetugid(0x7FFF778D3DC0, 0x0, 0x7FDEA8C062C8)       = 0 0
getuid(0x7FFF54902EE4, 0x0, 0x7FFF54904960)      = 0 0
issetugid(0x7FFF8808BA90, 0x7FFF549045F4, 0x7FFF54904960)        = 0 0
issetugid(0x7FFF758FA678, 0x0, 0x0)      = 0 0
read(0x4, "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC \"-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN\" \"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd\">\n<plist version=\"1.0\">\n<dict>\n\t<key>BuildMachineOSBuild</key>\n\t<string>13C40z</string>\n\t<key>CFBundleDevelopmentReg", 0x4E5)      = 1253 0
close(0x4)       = 0 0
stat64("/System/Library/Extensions/pptp.ppp/Contents/MacOS/PPTP\0", 0x7FFF54903C08, 0x7FFF54904156)      = 0 0
stat64("/System/Library/Extensions/pptp.ppp/Contents/MacOS/PPTP\0", 0x7FFF54902E88, 0x7FFF54903D30)      = 0 0
stat64("/System/Library/Extensions/pptp.ppp/Contents/MacOS/PPTP\0", 0x7FFF54903B18, 0xF4290)         = 0 0
open("/System/Library/Extensions/pptp.ppp/Contents/MacOS/PPTP\0", 0x0, 0x1FF)    = 4 0
close(0x4)       = 0 0
stat64("/System/Library/Extensions/pptp.ppp/Contents/MacOS/PPTP\0", 0x7FFF54902E68, 0x7FFF54903D10)      = 0 0
open("/System/Library/Extensions/pptp.ppp/Contents/MacOS/PPTP\0", 0x0, 0x0)  = 4 0
pread(0x4, "\317\372\355\376\a\0", 0x1000, 0x0)      = 4096 0
fcntl(0x4, 0x3D, 0x7FFF54901170)         = 0 0
mmap(0x10B392000, 0x5000, 0x5, 0x12, 0x4, 0x0)       = 0x10B392000 0
mmap(0x10B397000, 0x1000, 0x3, 0x12, 0x4, 0x5000)        = 0x10B397000 0
mmap(0x10B398000, 0x3B00, 0x1, 0x12, 0x4, 0x6000)        = 0x10B398000 0
close(0x4)       = 0 0
__sysctl(0x7FFF54902800, 0x2, 0x7FFF54902810)        = 0 0
getuid(0x7FDEA9001D30, 0x7FFF54902AA0, 0x0)      = 0 0
getgid(0x7FDEA9001D35, 0x7FFF54902AA0, 0x0)      = 0 0
access("/etc/localtime\0", 0x4, 0x7)         = 0 0
open_nocancel("/etc/localtime\0", 0x0, 0x0)      = 5 0
fstat64(0x5, 0x7FFF54902B30, 0x0)        = 0 0
read_nocancel(0x5, "TZif\0", 0x2A64)         = 1323 0
close_nocancel(0x5)      = 0 0
thread_selfid(0x10B3AD000, 0x7FFF77A55258, 0x1010101)        = 88910 0
__pthread_sigmask(0x1, 0x10B3ACECC, 0x0)         = 0 0
kevent64(0x5, 0x10B3AC458, 0x1)      = 1 0
madvise(0x10B401000, 0x1000, 0x5)        = 0 0
madvise(0x10B601000, 0x1000, 0x5)        = 0 0
kevent64(0x5, 0x10B3AC4F8, 0x1)      = 1 0
kevent64(0x5, 0x0, 0x0)      = 1 0
madvise(0x10B801000, 0x1000, 0x5)        = 0 0
kevent64(0x5, 0x10B3AC4F8, 0x1)      = 1 0
thread_selfid(0x10BC81000, 0x7FFF77A55258, 0x1010101)        = 88911 0
kevent64(0x5, 0x10BC80D28, 0x1)      = 1 0
kevent64(0x5, 0x7FFF75519130, 0x1)       = 1 0
workq_kernreturn(0x20, 0x0, 0x1)         = 0 0
kevent64(0x5, 0x0, 0x0)      = 1 0
workq_kernreturn(0x20, 0x0, 0x1)         = 0 0
socket(0x20, 0x3, 0x1)       = 7 0
ioctl(0x7, 0x800C6502, 0x7FFF549042D0)       = 0 0
__sysctl(0x7FFF54902460, 0x2, 0x7FFF54902470)        = 0 0
getuid(0x7FDEA9001D45, 0x7FFF54902700, 0x0)      = 0 0
getgid(0x7FDEA9001D4A, 0x7FFF54902700, 0x0)      = 0 0
write(0x1, "Fri Mar 28 10:31:10 2014 : \0", 0x1B)        = 27 0
write(0x1, "PPTP connecting to server '11.22.33.44' (11.22.33.44)...\0", 0x3C)       = 60 0
write(0x1, "\n\0", 0x1)      = 1 0
socket(0x2, 0x1, 0x0)        = 8 0
setsockopt(0x8, 0x6, 0x20)       = 0 0
connect(0x8, 0x7FFF549042E0, 0x10)       = -1 Err#49
__sysctl(0x7FFF54902460, 0x2, 0x7FFF54902470)        = 0 0
getuid(0x7FDEA9001D3F, 0x7FFF54902700, 0x0)      = 0 0
getgid(0x7FDEA9001D44, 0x7FFF54902700, 0x0)      = 0 0
write(0x1, "Fri Mar 28 10:31:10 2014 : \0", 0x1B)        = 27 0
write(0x1, "PPTP connect errno = 49 Can't assign requested address\0", 0x36)     = 54 0
write(0x1, "\n\0", 0x1)      = 1 0
close(0x7)       = 0 0
close(0x8)       = 0 0
workq_kernreturn(0x20, 0x0, 0x1)         = 0 0
kevent64(0x5, 0x7FFF75519130, 0x1)       = -1 Err#4
```

25 in hexadecimal is 0x19 but this number does not appear anywhere.

Comment: It doesn't answer directly your question but maybe `strace` could give you some hint on what is happening and what is the cause of the error. Well... you know the cause actually... but it could tell you where the error return code comes from.

Comment: @lgeorget, thanks for the suggestion. `strace` is not available on OSX but I used `dtruss` and updated my question with its output. I still can't see where did magic number `25` come from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [the OSX 1.9 pppd source code](http://opensource.apple.com/source/ppp/ppp-727.1.15/), I found this in `Helpers/pppd/pppd.h`:

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
#define EXIT_TERMINAL_FAILED    20
#define EXIT_DEVICE_ERROR   21
#endif
#ifdef MAXOCTETS
#ifdef __APPLE__
#define EXIT_TRAFFIC_LIMIT  22
#else
#define EXIT_TRAFFIC_LIMIT  20
#define EXIT_CNID_AUTH_FAILED   21
#endif
#endif
#ifdef __APPLE__
#define EXIT_PEER_NOT_AUTHORIZED    23
#define EXIT_CNID_AUTH_FAILED   24
#define EXIT_PEER_UNREACHABLE 25
#endif
```

So Apple has some exit codes of its own, and yours is defined as `EXIT_PEER_UNREACHABLE`.  Without going into too much detail, it looks like this exit code is only used if a plugin fails (at `Helpers/pppd/main.c` line 638).

Comment: That's brilliant! This means that OSX documentation about pppd [https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/pppd.8.html] is incomplete as they're listing only errors in range 0 to 19.

Comment: Yep.  Now that I look, exit codes 20-22 are also defined in that file.  I'll add them to my answer.